# jQuery Execution Repeats Itself / .FadeIn / .Hide

Tags: jquery, html, hide, fadein, fadeout

The following code displays a notification bar / tool tip on top of a webpage. It is set to display the bar about every minute. However it repeats the display right after the hide.
We only want to display the notification bar every minute. It seems like it works fine if I am using the page but whenever I step outside of the page it behaves weirdly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $('#notification_hdr').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        displayNotificationBar();
    }, 72000);

    function displayNotificationBar() {
        $('#notification_hdr').fadeIn(2000).delay(12000).hide(2000);
    }

    $('#close_btn').click(function () {
        $('#notification_hdr').hide(2000)
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: The code seems good to me, can you reproduce this in JSFiddle? And which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: You can make it shorter... `setInterval(displayNotificationBar, 72000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#notification_hdr').hide();
var T = setInterval(displayNotificationBar, 72000);

function displayNotificationBar(){
    $('#notification_hdr').fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $(this).delay(10000).hide(2000);    
    });
}

$('#close_btn').click(function() { 
    clearInterval(T);
    $('#notification_hdr').stop(true, true).hide(2000);
});
```

Chaining should work, but this should most definitely work, if it doesn't I would think your problem lies other places.

Comment: What's the point of using the callback to fadeIn instead of just chaining it?

Comment: In my experience sometimes chaining and just returning the object messes up in the exact same way Kevin decribed (and it was the only thing I could think of :) ), just using the callback seems to be more reliable, and usually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

May be better change displayNotificationBar function in this way:

```
    function displayNotificationBar() {
        $('#notification_hdr').fadeIn(2000).delay(12000);
        if( $('#notification_hdr').is(':visible') ) {
             $('#notification_hdr').hide(2000)
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JamesMontagne I have fixed it. Thanks, it was just a wrong cut&paste :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a recursive function that gets called in the complete callback of hide()

```
function displayNotificationBar() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#notification_hdr').fadeIn(2000).delay(12000).hide(2000,displayNotificationBar    );
    },72000)
}

displayNotificationBar()
```